# Can't access node modules

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

I'm new with nodejs and as a C#/C++ programmer I would like to use typescript to type a little bit my code.

When i'm trying to import/require modules such as fs or stream I get this error:

> couldn't found the module

(Those module are find by VisualStudio 2017 from within `C:\Users\0xCDCDCDCD\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TypeScript\2.5\node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts`)
However if i'm trying to use ReadableStreamReader it seem to be able to find it without any need to import/require it (which is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.5\lib.d.ts`)

Every article I found talk about the need of `.d.ts` and to `npm install @types/node` if needed.
I tried it but it won't fix my issue.

I also tried to add

```
// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts" />
```

as the first line of my `.ts` file (as well as the absolute path, and the absolute path from the TypeScript 2.5 directory) without success.

Comment: I'm attempting to reproduce the issue in typescript 2.5 but can't seem to. Could you show the source of the file giving the error, as well as your `tsconfig.json` and your `package.json`? If you haven't already, I'd suggest doing `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your `tsconfig.json`, and also upgrade to TypeScript 2.7.1 if you can.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. You can look at sources here: https://pastebin.com/PhxYK2Hq Take note the tsconfig.json have been manually created NOW because I'm using visualstudio and there is none (maybe the project file contains it as xml? have too look). Also I found out SOME project in my VisualStudio seem to have TypeScript option and other not, which is wierd. (And from the documentation it should use node because i'm not using AMD, ES2015 or something else)

Comment: And i'm sorry I did fail when writing down the file extensions, you should read hello.ts and app.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seem I now have a project I can compile now.

I don't quite have the absolute answer but a thing that didn't help me is the fact I don't know what I'm doing(TM). (and I mean i'm learning both TypeScript and NodeJS at the same time).

Thing I found out:

- Don't trust the editor about errors, trust the VisualStudio output.

  I had the error again for a while (and it wasn't able to find out the definition either) but end up being able to compile and run it. Later one it did remove the error and found the definitions (aka the types).
  Maybe the error keep there because I was wrongly using stream.Readable as the return type for a method that was returning nothing...
- Also for other stupid people like me (in my own word) TypeScript has is own syntax (like the import, interface, ...) and it convert some code to javascript (and ignore some other). NodeJS then execute the javascript.

  This mean require() still work in .ts and you have to use it for global module. (like fs and stream), this also mean if i'm using a regular nodejs project I would need to use require() to import my ts classes.
- In VisualStudio there is two way to create a nodejs project, one in the Other languages/JavaScript/Node.js and Other languages/TypeScript/Node.js. I did use the last one now. I think the only thing it will add is the ability to use the build-in configuration tab for TypeScript after deleting the tsconfig.json file.

  So yes, Visual Studio seem to manage the ts configuration in the background without generating the file on the drive
- I did try to install tsd manually (I had a previously installed nodejs with npm; just in case to be sure)

  > npm install tsd -g
- When I created the TypeScript project, VisualStudio found out the tsconfig.json and because of it won't allow me to use the embeded TypeScript settings tab.